# Hi, I'm trying to make a percentage calculator. I have an array and I want to see the number of times each element occurs

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a percentage calculator. I have an array and I want to see the number of times each element occurs and then divide it by the total number of occurrences to get a percentage. So I want an output like:
*/ 1 = 12%
*/ 2 = 15%
...

```
        int[] n1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6 };

        int c = n1.Count();

        Console.WriteLine ("the total number of " + c );
        Dictionary<int, int> counts = n1.GroupBy (x => x).ToDictionary (g => g.Key, g => g.Count ());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might find your experience here better if you visit the FAQ first, particularly http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
int[] n1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6 };

int c = n1.Count();

var keyValue = n1.GroupBy (n => n).Select (n=> new KeyValuePair<int,string>(n.Key,((decimal)n.Count()/(decimal)c).ToString("0.0%")));
```

Response:

```
Key = 1, Value = 18.8%
Key = 2, Value = 18.8%
Key = 3, Value = 12.5%
Key = 4, Value = 12.5%
Key = 5, Value = 18.8%
Key = 6, Value = 18.8%
```